# Fill Down Formula based on data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to build a macro to fill down formulas.Data is being copied from a website and pasted on `Sheet1` separately. `Sheet2` contains formulas to clean up and arrange the data including eliminating rows based on a criteria. The problem is that if I fill down the formulas prior to eliminating the rows, I get a `#REF` error. I want to include the fill down in the macro because I already have one to delete the rows. I do not want to substitute character 160 for an actual space.  My macro is placed below.

Code:

```
Sub chng()

    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 2).Value = "SA" Or Cells(x, 2).Value = "EVC" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Columns("A:A").Select


    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

In other words what I want to accomplish is once I have finished pasting the info, run the macro, delete the rows, change character 160 for an actual space then count the rows (not including headers) on `Sheet1` and fill down on `sheet2` based on that e.g. if I have 140 rows of data I want to fill down from row 2 until 141.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the number of rows and decrement it for each row you delete, then use that range:

```
Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, totalRows As Long
totalRows = lastrow

    Rows(x).Delete
    totalRows = totalRows - 1
```

Then you can copy down your formulas from row 2 to totalRows, in whatever column it is.

Comment: Edit this section:

    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, totalRows As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    totalRows=lastrow
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 2).Value = "SA" Or Cells(x, 2).Value = "EVC" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
            totalRows = totalRows - 1
        End If
    Next x

The formatting may be a little odd in this comment. Do you already have code for copying the formulas down?